# Make an empty span tag appear full width using no padding/margin/&nbsp;

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty sure someone is just messing with me, but they asked me to do this.

Put a span tag inside a table, with nothing inside the span tag. And somehow make the span tag 16px wide.

No padding, margin or &nbsp. I dont think its even possible.
Is it possible? Heres my HTML/CSS.

```
    .test{
        height: 31px;
        width: 16px;
        background-color: red;
     }


        <td>16px wide</td>
        <td><span class="test"></span></td>
        <td>16px wide</td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply set:

```
.test{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
}
```